# Wordpress: Is it possible to make two types of pagination on one page (by page and by month)?

Tags: wordpress, pagination, custom-wordpress-pages

Is it possible to make two types of pagination on one page (by page and by month)?

Currently I have pagination by month.

```
<?php
  $args = array(
  'post_type'    => 'reviews',
  'type'         => 'monthly',
  'echo'         => 0
  );
 echo wp_get_archives($args); 
?>

 <div class="row reviews-items">
  <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
   <div class="reviews-item-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
   <div class="reviews-item-text"><?php the_content(); ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
 </div>
```

I have tried to add the following code below
`<?echo paginate_links();?>`
It displays a pagination block, URLs works, but there is no content.

Comment: U want next prev month navigation ? Archives have pagination by default if not turned off .

Comment: It can be next and prev months. How to do it? Currently, I have a pagination block of all months displayed above reviews, but is it possible to add another one of next and prev months pagination below all reviews?